# XPath Check Node is Blank

Tags: xml, xpath

Using XPath, how to check if the node or tag value is blank?

Given the Sample XML:

Questions (Need XPath expression for the following):
1. how will I check if ExceptionMessage1 is blank.
2. how will I check if ExceptionMessage2 @nil == true?
3. how about if there will be ExceptionMessage3, it can either be:
       a. Contains exception message
       b. No message, with @nil="true" (Combined ExceptionMessage1 & ExceptionMessage2 behaviors)

```
<Envelope>
   <Body>
      <SellResponse>
         <SellResult>
            <ExceptionMessage1>JourneyManager.SellJourney(segment): Segment already booked under different class of service</ExceptionMessage1>
            <ExceptionMessage2 nil="true"/>
            <NSProcessTime>0</NSProcessTime>
            <ProcessTime>0</ProcessTime>
            <Booking nil="true"/>
            <Success nil="true"/>
            <Warning nil="true"/>
            <Error nil="true"/>
            <OtherServiceInformations nil="true"/>
         </SellResult>
      </SellResponse>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

TIA

Comment: I don't understand. What kind of answer you are looking for? What do you mean by check i.e what kind of value do you want the XPath to return?

Comment: I needed an expression for checking if ExceptionMessage1 is blank or not. Also, check ExceptionMessage2 nil attribute value is true or not. I am expecting boolean results for both expressions needed. Lastly, If there will be ExceptionMessage3, and if it has a message... it would be displayed the same as ExceptionMessage1, if not (meaning blank)... it will be blank with the attribute nil="true". With ExceptionMessage3, I want to check if it is not blank or nil=true. All I need are expressions.

Answer (score 6):

> *"check if ExceptionMessage1 is blank"*

The following should return `true` if `ExceptionMessage1` has child node (not blank) and return `false` otherwise :

```
not(//ExceptionMessage1/node())
```

> *"check if ExceptionMessage2 @nil == true"*

This is straightforward, I think :

```
boolean(//ExceptionMessage2/@nil = 'true')
```

> *"With ExceptionMessage3, I want to check if it is not blank or nil=true"*

The following XPath returns `true`, if there is `ExceptionMessage3` that is not blank or has attribute `nil` equals 'true' :

```
boolean(//ExceptionMessage3[node() or @nil='true'])
```

You might be able to omit `boolean()` call if the context explicitly expects a boolean value. The conversion will be automatic in that case.

Comment: I tried #1 in (http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-xpath-tester.html) and got the error "Can't run xpath :TypeError: Failed to execute 'iterateNext' on 'XPathResult': The result type is not an iterator.". Item #2 solution is correct, but when I change nil attribute's value to "false". it returns the same error as #1.

Comment: @BorgyManotoy seems like the tool can't handle that. I used to try XPath in one of these tools : [1](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath), [2](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/), [3](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Comment: Everything is working, the problem was the xpath tester site I am using. Thank you so much har07. I like the tester (http://xpatheval.apphb.com). Maybe it was because of the xpath version of the online xpath tester I am using.

Comment: @BorgyManotoy Thanks, [I made that one](https://github.com/har07/XPathEval), acctually!

Answer (score 2):

I guess somebody might encounter similar issues like this, so I just post the solutions I gather from Lech & har07, thanks guys.

I use the online XPath Tester (http://xpatheval.apphb.com)

1. how will I check if ExceptionMessage1 is blank or empty string.
   //ExceptionMessage1/text() = ''
   http://xpatheval.apphb.com/KHg6afoO2

   empty(//ExceptionMessage1/text())
   http://xpatheval.apphb.com/lZHxs8BO6
2. how will I check if ExceptionMessage2 @nil == true?
   //ExceptionMessage2/@nil = 'true'
   http://xpatheval.apphb.com/8Tf7Kf8yx

   boolean(//ExceptionMessage2/@nil = 'true')
   http://xpatheval.apphb.com/_KcXIH9fU

   If the attribute nil's value is false, it will also return false
3. how about if there will be ExceptionMessage3, it can either be:
   a. Contains exception message
   b. No message, with @nil="true" (Combined ExceptionMessage1 &   ExceptionMessage2 behaviors)

   ```
   <Envelope>    
      <Body>    
          <SellResponse>    
              <SellResult>    
                  <ExceptionMessage1>JourneyManager.SellJourney(segment): Segment already booked under different class of service</ExceptionMessage1>    
                  <ExceptionMessage2 nil="true"/>    
                  <ExceptionMessage3 nil="false">JourneyManager.SellJourney(segment): No funds to proceed with the transaction</ExceptionMessage3>    
                  <NSProcessTime>0</NSProcessTime>    
                  <ProcessTime>0</ProcessTime>    
                  <Booking nil="true"/>    
                  <Success nil="true"/>    
                  <Warning nil="true"/>    
                  <Error nil="true"/>    
                  <OtherServiceInformations nil="true"/>    
              </SellResult>    
          </SellResponse>    
      </Body>    
   </Envelope>
   ```

   - Check if empty or nil="true"
     empty(//ExceptionMessage3/text()) or //ExceptionMessage3/@nil = "true"
     http://xpatheval.apphb.com/qp2ejO_y1
   - Check if not empty or nil="false"
     not(empty(//ExceptionMessage3/text())) or //ExceptionMessage3/@nil = "false"
     http://xpatheval.apphb.com/v1b72d6ZK

Thanks Lech Rzedzicki & har07 for the help.

Answer (score 1):

1. `//ExceptionMessage1/text() = ''` - it will check if the content of the element is an empty string - just google any Xpath tutorial for more examples or if you need the inverse.
2. `//ExceptionMessage2/@nil = 'true'`
3. Just use `or` to combine the two Xpaths above

Comment: I tried it on http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-xpath-tester.html, but it won't accept... #1 - the ( = '') expression is returning TypeError. #2 gets TypeError when I change the value of the nil attribute into "false".

Comment: Thanks Bro, both solutions worked for me. The problem was on the online xpath tester I am using to my tests.