# Retrive data from XML in Java and insert data in Oracle

Tags: java, xml, oracle, insert, unmarshalling

I have used JAXB Unmarshaler in Java to retrive data from XML into Java objects which is working fine.

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;    

public class FRDDbImportWorkflow {


     public static void main(String...args) throws FileNotFoundException {

          File xmlFile = new File("//home/tr.xml");       

          try {             

              JAXBContext jaxbContext  = JAXBContext.newInstance(FRD115Type.class);

              Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

              JAXBElement<FRD115Type> jaxbElement = (JAXBElement<Fd115Type>) jaxbUnmarshaller
                        .unmarshal(new StreamSource(xmlFile), Fd115Type.class);

              FRD115Type obj = jaxbElement.getValue();

              System.out.println(obj.getRptHdr().getEnvText()); 
           } catch (JAXBException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
       }

    }

}
```

Now i want to create another java class which will insert this data into Oracle table. As i have many xml element in xml file then do i need to create `get method` for all this element to retrive the data from xml and then insert into Oracle ?

Is there any other parser technique used instead of creating `get method` for all this xml element ?

I am also not sure how to insert this xml data into Oracle. I have created below table in Oracle :

```
CREATE TABLE
    IMPORT_XML
    (
        fd115 VARCHAR2(180),
        RPTHDR VARCHAR2(180),
        EXCHNAM VARCHAR2(50),
        ENVTEXT VARCHAR2(20),
        RPTCOD VARCHAR2(20),
        RPTNAM VARCHAR2(180),
        RPTFLEXKEY VARCHAR2(180),
        MEMBID VARCHAR2(50),
        MEMBLGLNAM VARCHAR2(80),
        RPTPRNTEFFDAT DATE,
        RPTPRNTEFFTIM VARCHAR2(50),
        RPTPRNTRUNDAT DATE,
        fd115GRP VARCHAR2(180),
        fd115KEYGRP VARCHAR2(180),
        PARTICIPANTGRP VARCHAR2(180),
        PARTICIPANT VARCHAR2(50),
        PARTLNGNAME VARCHAR2(50),
        fd115GRP1 VARCHAR2(180),
        fd115KEYGRP1 VARCHAR2(180),
        BUSINESSUNITGRP VARCHAR2(180),
        BUSINESSUNIT VARCHAR2(180),
        BUSUNTLNGNAME VARCHAR2(50),
        BUSINESSUNITID NUMBER(30,9),
        fd115GRP2 VARCHAR2(180),
        fd115KEYGRP2 VARCHAR2(180),
        USER_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
        USERNUMERICID NUMBER(30,9),
        fd115REC1 VARCHAR2(180),
        USRGROUP VARCHAR2(50),
        USER_LEVEL VARCHAR2(10),
        LOGNAM VARCHAR2(50),
        ISUSFLG NUMBER(30,9),
        EFFSTATUS NUMBER(30,9),
        DELPROTECTED VARCHAR2(10),
        ENABLEPROPRIETARYACCT VARCHAR2(10),
        ENABLEAGENCYACCT VARCHAR2(10),
        ENABLEMARKETMAKINGACCT VARCHAR2(10),
        ENABLEBESTACCT VARCHAR2(10),
        ENABLERISKLESSPRINCIPALACCT VARCHAR2(10),
        MAXORDERVALUE VARCHAR2(100),
        MAXORDRQTY VARCHAR2(100),
        SETTLACCT NUMBER(30,9),
        SETTLLOCAT VARCHAR2(50),
        fd115GRP3 VARCHAR2(180),
        fd115KEYGRP3 VARCHAR2(180),
        MKTGRPNAM VARCHAR2(50),
        fd115REC2 VARCHAR2(180),
        ENTROLE VARCHAR2(50),
        fd115GRP4 VARCHAR2(180),
        TESTYPE NUMBER(30,9),
        TESELIGIBILITY NUMBER(30,9)
    );
```

Comment: Your XML appears to be invalid as it is missing the `</fd115Grp>` and `</fd115Grp1>` closing tags.

Comment: Sorry but i didnt placed complete xml as its bit large ..do you want complete xml file ?

Comment: No, better would be a [MRE] which had only 10-20 data points but was representative of your data (and was valid XML) so that we don't have to deal with a huge document (but its also relevant that your data is larger than 4000 bytes so would need to be passed as a CLOB) but where you could extrapolate the techniques used in the answers and apply it to your (larger) data-set.

Comment: Its also not clear where some columns in the table (such as the first `fd115` column) relate to the XML document.

Comment: i have edited xml and fd115 column i have just added ..i think its of no use so i will delete this column and also the other header column which not needed...the xml is not that large its just 1.5MB in size so i think we dont need to use CLOB here

Comment: As I said, use a [MRE] it should have only a few lines of XML but enough to represent your problem and you should define how the XML structure maps to the table and also include your expected output - so if you are expecting multiple rows to be inserted then you need to describe that. The data set is **TOO BIG** and the problem is not well enough defined that in attempting to answer one part we are missing all your other expectations because you haven't adequately defined what you want and how to get there in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `XMLTABLE`. Something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO import_xml (
  EXCHNAM,
  ENVTEXT,
  RPTCOD,
  RPTNAM,
  RPTFLEXKEY,
  MEMBID,
  MEMBLGLNAM,
  RPTPRNTEFFDAT,
  RPTPRNTRUNDAT,
  PARTICIPANT
)
SELECT EXCHNAM,
       ENVTEXT,
       RPTCOD,
       RPTNAM,
       RPTFLEXKEY,
       MEMBID,
       MEMBLGLNAM,
       RPTPRNTEFFDAT + ( TO_TIMESTAMP( RPTPRNTEFFTIM, 'HH24:MI:SS.FF2' )
                       - TO_TIMESTAMP( '00:00:00.00', 'HH24:MI:SS.FF2' ) ),
       RPTPRNTRUNDAT,
       PARTICIPANT
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         XMLNAMESPACES( DEFAULT 'http://www.eu.com/technology' ),
         '//fd115'
         PASSING XMLType( your_xml )
         COLUMNS
           EXCHNAM        VARCHAR2(50)  PATH './rptHdr/exchNam',
           ENVTEXT        VARCHAR2(20)  PATH './rptHdr/envText',
           RPTCOD         VARCHAR2(20)  PATH './rptHdr/rptCod',
           RPTNAM         VARCHAR2(180) PATH './rptHdr/rptNam',
           RPTFLEXKEY     VARCHAR2(180) PATH './rptHdr/rptFlexKey',
           MEMBID         VARCHAR2(50)  PATH './rptHdr/membId',
           MEMBLGLNAM     VARCHAR2(80)  PATH './rptHdr/membLglNam',
           RPTPRNTEFFDAT  TIMESTAMP     PATH './rptHdr/rptPrntEffDat',
           RPTPRNTEFFTIM  VARCHAR2(50)  PATH './rptHdr/rptPrntEffTim',
           RPTPRNTRUNDAT  DATE          PATH './rptHdr/rptPrntRunDat',
           PARTICIPANT    VARCHAR2(50)  PATH './fd115Grp/fd115KeyGrp/participantGrp/participant'
       );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0b671c3b3316e12a8af1c80d815efb24)

*(You'll need to check the XQuery paths and add in all the extra columns but this should give you an example of the syntax you can use.)*

Also, `RPTPRNTEFFDAT` can have the `TIMESTAMP` data type and store both the `RPTPRNTEFFDAT` and `RPTPRNTEFFTIM` xml data. (You could use a `DATE` column but the `RPTPRNTEFFTIM` data appears to have fractional seconds and you would lose that precision.)

```sql
CREATE TABLE
    IMPORT_XML
    (
        fd115 VARCHAR2(180),
        RPTHDR VARCHAR2(180),
        EXCHNAM VARCHAR2(50),
        ENVTEXT VARCHAR2(20),
        RPTCOD VARCHAR2(20),
        RPTNAM VARCHAR2(180),
        RPTFLEXKEY VARCHAR2(180),
        MEMBID VARCHAR2(50),
        MEMBLGLNAM VARCHAR2(80),
        RPTPRNTEFFDAT TIMESTAMP, -- TIMESTAMP and remove the RPTPRNTEFFTIM column
        RPTPRNTRUNDAT DATE,
        fd115GRP VARCHAR2(180),
        fd115KEYGRP VARCHAR2(180),
        PARTICIPANTGRP VARCHAR2(180),
        PARTICIPANT VARCHAR2(50),
   ...
```

Comment: how do i check check the XQuery paths ? and how will i use this query in Java ?

Comment: The base path is `//fd115` which should correspond to your root element; then each column has a path that should reflect the path in the XML structure to the data. I'm not sure I got them correct as I was typing it out by hand; you'll need to check that they are correct. As for using it in java ... its a SQL statement so you create a prepared statement and can use `PASSING XMLType( ? )` in the middle and pass your XML file as a CLOB bind parameter to the prepared statement and then just execute it on the database as you would with any other prepared statement.

Comment: just want to know can i run this sql query in oracle database directly and how to run it? so that i can confirm what data i am receiving and also filter out the column which not needed ...PASSING XMLType( your_xml_value_passed_as_a_clob_bind_variable ) what i need to pass here ?

Comment: @Andrew Updated to add the `XMLNAMESPACES` and link to a db<>fiddle with an example of calling the SQL from an anonymous PL/SQL block (you can just call the SQL directly from Java and pass the CLOB as a bind variable without the surrounding PL/SQL that I used to store the bind variable).

Comment: i am just trying to run the statement in fiddle in sql developer and getting error as [Code: 17439, SQL State: 99999]  Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED and also encounter the symbol error ...cant i run it in database just to test at once so that i can try the same in java then ?

Comment: @Andrew The code in the db<>fiddle works in at least Oracle 11gR2 and later. If you are using an earlier version then check that is supports `XMLTABLE` and `XMLTYPE` and if it doesn't then you'll need to update your question and specify what version you are using and investigate a different method of extracting data from XML (try the `EXTRACT` or `EXTRACTVALUE` functions).

Comment: i am using Oracle 18C version in Oracle and its also giving an error at line 430 'Encounter the Symbol when expecting one of the following:' ...i just took the complete block from fiddle and try to run in the sql developer

Comment: Changed the version to 18c [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0b671c3b3316e12a8af1c80d815efb24) and it works. Since its PL/SQL, are you running it in SQL Developer as a script (`F5` keyboard shortcut) rather than as a statement (`ctrl-Enter` keyboard shortcut)? Beyond that suggestion, I'm not sure I can assist in getting otherwise working code to run on your local machine.

Comment: yes thanks it works i will try in java now :)..one question why its not inserted all the data from xml and only one row ?

Comment: I mean do we need to loop this insert using select query or it will select all the xml data ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54668633/xml-oracle-identify-existing-but-empty-element/54674037#54674037 gives an example of how to generate multiple rows through successive `LEFT OUTER JOIN` of correlated `XMLTABLE`s; you just need to define how the XML structure should be map to multiple rows and then you can apply the same technique in SQL. You could equally do it in Java with loops and submit a batch of rows to reduce the number of network requests. Whichever you chose should probably be based on which method you understand better and can maintain in the future.

Comment: ok i wil l try my problem is i am quiet new to java and for this reason i have created another question so that i can create jdbc connection and try to insert the data from xml into oracle table...as u can see in the fiddle example i have multiple  entrole,participant and many elements which has more then one value so i need to get all this in oracle table

Comment: i coule have done this easily using oracle stored procedure and functionbut i need to use java for the same

Comment: i have modified my previous question which i am trying now using SAX parser to loop through xml data